# Writing URL Links into Elgg Database

Tags: php, mysql, social-networking, elgg

I need to be able to create a page where a user can share links with fellow members.  I want to store these URLs in an SQL database so that I can check to see if each link posted is unique or if it has been shared before.

From what I've read, creating and customizing my own elgg SQL database ***is not*** the way to go.  So, I need a little direction as to how to go about doing this within the current elgg (1.8.13) framework. I would think that I would need to create my own database but maybe someone can fill me in as to where this data would be stored?

Comment: The version of Elgg I've used is very old, but at least in this version, you can set your own custom attributes on each account.  I would recommend looking into that.

Comment: Thanks Brad, did some reading up on the data model after your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should:

1. Read up on Elgg's data model http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Engine/DataModel
2. Follow their tutorials to understand how to create a plugin using this data model.
3. Sign up for an account at elgg.org for more timely response. http://docs.elgg.org/wiki/Tutorials/Blog
4. Do your sanity a favor and buy this book: [http://www.amazon.com/Elgg-Social-Networking-Cash-Costello/dp/1849511306](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1849511306)

The bottom line is that Elgg provides you with a data abstraction layer so that you don't need to write your SQL manually.

P/s: if you are not too familiar with PHP, I'd recommend trying something else. But it's just my opinion.